# How to install usbserial and ftdi_sio modules to 14.04 Trusty Vagrant box?

Tags: usb, kernel, vagrant

I started a Vagrant box from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box. For some reason, this box does not seem to include **usbserial** and **ftdi_sio** modules by default. How to install them?

I have verified that modules are really missing with `lsmod`. Also `modprobe usbserial` throws `modprobe: FATAL: Module usbserial not found.` (as it does with `ftdi_sio` too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linux kernel team decided to remove some modules from the base kernel to allow "virtual" images to be [slimmed down](http://ubuntu.5.x6.nabble.com/PATCH-0-2-linux-image-extra-support-td365008.html). The extra modules are moved into linux-image-extra and you can get them installed by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

Comment: Huge thanks. For my VMware virtualized Ubuntu Trusty this answer, and a reboot(!), made my FTDI devices work.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`

works on my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS which startup by vagrant

```
[16:02:42 ~] $ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0403:6010 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT2232C Dual USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

[16:02:51 ~] $ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Nov 16 16:02 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 1 Nov 16 16:02 /dev/ttyUSB1
```